# Having problems attempting to grab the row of a ASP.NET DataGrid Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So I have a ASP.NET DataGrid and in the SomeName_ItemBound I am trying to set the visibility of the row if certain conditions are met.  However, I can't seem to find a way to acquire the row.

How do I select the current row in the:

```
SomeName_ItemBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `DataGrid` is an old control you should use `GridView`, I guess you must be using GridView already.
- You can get current row by `e.Item` inside your ItemBound event

like

```
protected void SomeName_ItemBound(Object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e) 
{
     // Use the ItemDataBound event to customize the DataGrid control. 
     // The ItemDataBound event allows you to access the data before 
     // the item is displayed in the control. In this example, the 
     // ItemDataBound event is used to format the items in the 
     // CurrencyColumn in currency format.
     if((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || 
         (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
     {
         // e.Item // is your current row
         e.Item.Visible = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I can't tell you how hard it was to try and track down such a simple answer.